# How can I set LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: variables, ubuntu, library-path

I want to set my `LIBRARY_PATH` permanently. I searched about it but there was guides for setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so I would be thankful if anyone help me. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You do that in `~/.bashrc`. On a new line, just enter:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=<path to your library files>:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then, run `source ~/.bashrc` to enable anything you've added there.

Comment: For clarification: the `:$LIBRARY_PATH` part appends anything that was previously set in the old variable into the new one.

Comment: using `export` doesn't change the variable permanently, it just set it in active shell.

Comment: Then, try changing `/etc/environment`, supposing by "permanent" you mean "system-wide"; see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables for details.